# Python convert comma separated list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am struggling to convert a comma separated list into a multi column (7) data-frame.

```
print (type(mylist))

<type 'list'>
Print(mylist)


['AN,2__AAS000,26,20150826113000,-283.000,20150826120000,-283.000',         'AN,2__AE000,26,20150826113000,0.000,20150826120000,0.000',.........
```

The following creates a frame of a single column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

I have reviewed the inbuilt csv functionality for Pandas, however my csv data is held in a list. How can I simply covert the list into a 7 column data-frame.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error : `l=[['AA','2__000',26,20150826113000,-283.000,20150826120000,-283.000],['BB','2__DI9',26,20150826113000,0.000,20150826120000,0.000],[
'CC','2__GH6',26,20150826113000,-269.000,20150826120000,-269.000]]
pd.DataFrame(l)` works fine

Comment: Can you post the output from `print(mylist)`

Comment: I have limited the results above as the are 2k rows. The dataframe is created however when i print(df) i get all the data followed by [1922 rows x 1 columns]

Comment: Can you post just the first few rows then, you have to show how the data is stored in your list so we can reproduce your error

Comment: As further background, the data is originally from a file which had mixture of CSV data and some metadata which i stripped out and passed the CSV rows to a list.

Comment: I have just updated the main text with actual output from the list. Thanks

Comment: No, I want to see the output from `print(mylist[:3])`

Comment: ['AN,2__AAS000,26,20150826113000,-283.000,20150826120000,-283.000', 'AN,2__AE000,26,20150826113000,0.000,20150826120000,0.000',

Comment: Your list looks like it's a list of strings rather than a list of lists, are there embedded carriage returns/new lines? Also edit this into your question, not as a comment

Comment: Thanks EdChum, you were on the ball.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to split each string in your list:

```
import  pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split(",") for sub in l])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0         1   2               3         4               5         6
0  AN  2__AS000  26  20150826113000  -283.000  20150826120000  -283.000
1  AN   2__A000  26  20150826113000     0.000  20150826120000     0.000
2  AN  2__AE000  26  20150826113000  -269.000  20150826120000  -269.000
3  AN  2__AE000  26  20150826113000  -255.000  20150826120000  -255.000
4  AN   2__AE00  26  20150826113000  -254.000  20150826120000  -254.000
```

If you know how many lines to skip in your csv you can do it all with read_csv using `skiprows=lines_of_metadata`:

```
import  pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("in.csv",skiprows=3,header=None)
print(df)
```

Or if each line of the metadata starts with a certain character you can use comment:

```
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv",header=None,comment="#")
```

If you need to specify more then one character you can combine `itertools.takewhile` which will drop lines starting with `xxx`:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import dropwhile
import csv
with open("in.csv") as f:
    f = dropwhile(lambda x: x.startswith("#!!"), f)
    r = csv.reader(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(r)
```

Using your input data adding some lines starting with #!!:

```
#!! various
#!! metadata
#!! lines
AN,2__AS000,26,20150826113000,-283.000,20150826120000,-283.000
AN,2__A000,26,20150826113000,0.000,20150826120000,0.000
AN,2__AE000,26,20150826113000,-269.000,20150826120000,-269.000
AN,2__AE000,26,20150826113000,-255.000,20150826120000,-255.000
AN,2__AE00,26,20150826113000,-254.000,20150826120000,-254.000
```

Outputs:

```
    0         1   2               3         4               5         6
0  AN  2__AS000  26  20150826113000  -283.000  20150826120000  -283.000
1  AN   2__A000  26  20150826113000     0.000  20150826120000     0.000
2  AN  2__AE000  26  20150826113000  -269.000  20150826120000  -269.000
3  AN  2__AE000  26  20150826113000  -255.000  20150826120000  -255.000
4  AN   2__AE00  26  20150826113000  -254.000  20150826120000  -254.000
```

Comment: Great work, appreciate the help this worked perfectly. Im very happy.

Comment: @user636322, no worries, I added a couple of ways to do it with read_csv, what does the metadata actually look like, do you know how many lines are there or do the lines start with a common character?

Comment: The metadata is basically repeating header information throughout the csv file. Im not able to predict location so i just used a loop to remove specifically( if row.startswith('xxx')).

Comment: @user636322, you can still do it when reading from the csv, what is the `xxx` in `startswith('xxx')`

Comment: Im actually selecting the valid data with the loop, and therefore eliminating the invalid data, in the example above row.startswith('AN').

Comment: You can apply the same logic, just keep the rows that have the first elements the start with "AN using a generator expression

Comment: The string splitting is perfect, but if your list also has a header row use `df.columns = df.iloc[0]` to name the columns with that first (zeroth) row and then remove that header row from the dataframe with `df = df[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

you can covert the list into a 7 column data-frame in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
```

Comment: Try to add some description with your code. What is does ? Why it work ?

Answer (score -1):

I encounter a similar problem. I solve it by this way.

```
def lrsplit(line):
    left, *_ , right = line.split('-')
    mid = '-'.join(_)
    return left, mid, right.strip()
example = pd.DataFrame(lrsplit(line) for line in open("example.csv"))
example.columns = ['location', 'position', 'company']
```

Result:

```
    location    position    company
0   india   manager intel
1   india   sales-manager   amazon
2   banglore    ccm- head - county  jp morgan
```