# Separate list in different columns and split the rows afterwards in a dataframe

Tags: python, linux, pandas

So, my input file is a large file containing a list within a list. It has thousands of rows. Each value in the list is either 0 or 1. There is also another column specifying a value associated with each list. However, after passing my data through pandas train_test_split the ends of the nested list appear to be separated from the rest of the list.

I have tried using pandas.read_csv and scikit train_test_split functions but this does not appear to solve the issue.
I have also tried using the dtype parameter in pandas.read_csv however this has not worked either.

```
data = pandas.read_csv('file_to_be_read', sep=',',)
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(data, test_size = 0.3, random_state  = 42)
```

Input file:
    [[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ..., [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]         4.567645

The resulting output:

```
[[0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]... [0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0      0.0]     4.567645
```

Desired Output:

```
[[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ..., [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]         4.567645
```

In essence I just want to take random rows of data from the original file and place them into another file.

Comment: `I just want to take random rows of data` - you may use `DataFrame.sample` and specify fraction or exact number of rows.

Comment: Does it somehow belongs to this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224363/python-convert-comma-separated-list-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: The format of the initial file is not csv. how can you expect `read_csv` to give correct output? You should read the file line by line, split it in 2 part with either a regex, and use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the list of list.