# How do I create a column in this Dataframe using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has comma separated values as the row content. Now I want to choose the first character of the content from each row and create a column out of those. [Dataframe Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XqSI.png)

For example, the first value of each row is 1, I want to create a column out of all the 1's and so on.

Comment: No dataframe image please.

Comment: your_dataframe['new_col'] = your_dataframe['old_col'].apply(lambda x: x[0])

Comment: It could be better to include the data in the question instead of linking to an external image.

Comment: This seems like you parsed the file incorrectly; numeric data shouldn't be stored in a DataFrame like that.

Comment: Please show the code you used to create the Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If your comma separated values were in a .csv file to begin with the easiest way is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('name.csv')
```

This way you get a dataframe with all the desired columns.
To access a single columns just use

```
df['first column name']
```

If you created the dataframe yourself you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split(",") for sub in df])
```

as proposed in [Python convert comma separated list to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224363/python-convert-comma-separated-list-to-pandas-dataframe)